# Hibernate: How to annotate three tables in one join table?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

How to annotate it?

Tables:

### GROUPS

### id   | int  |

### name | text |

### TEACHERS

### id   | int  |

### name | text |

### SUBJECTS

### id   | int  |

### name | text |

I need to annotate them with

### GROUP_SUBJECT_TEACHER

### id_group   | int  |

### id_subject | int  |

### id_teacher | int  |

Comment: You have mentioned 2 GROUPS table, is it a typo ? Is the third table is SUBJECT ? What type of relations these 3 have ? Are all ManyToMany ?

Comment: Sorry.

They are all ManyToMany.

Comment: Sorry.

 GROUPS,
 SUBJECTS,
 TEACHERS. 

They are all ManyToMany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GROUP_SUBJECT_TEACHER** will be mapped as an Entity called **GroupSubjectTeacher**:

each of Group, Teacher and Subject will have **OneToMany** relationship with GroupSubjectTeacher
and GroupSubjectTeacher  will have **ManyToOne** relationship with each of other entities

if you need more explanation, don't hesitate to ask